# center images with text underneath in a nav

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, nav

I want to make a nav bar using images but still have text under each image, yet I also want the text to be centered.

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="whatwedo-wrapper" id="whatwedo">
                    <div class="whatwedo">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <img class="services" src="images/Brand-Online-Circle-Blue.png" width="200px"
                                onmouseover="this.src='images/Brand-Online-Circle-Grey.png'"
                                onmouseout="this.src='images/Brand-Online-Circle-Blue.png'">
                                <br>
                                Brand Online
                            </li>
                            <li>

                                <img class="services" src="images/Brand-Marketing-Circle-Blue.png" width="200px"
                                onmouseover="this.src='images/Brand-Marketing-Circle-Grey.png'"
                                onmouseout="this.src='images/Brand-Marketing-Circle-Blue.png'">
                                <br>
                                Brand Management

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and I have made what I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/B7sdp/

The overall outcome I am looking for is for the images to be centered and the text to be underneath its image, also centred.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `text-align:center` property to your `li` and replace `float:left` with `display:inline-block`

```
.whatwedo li {
width: 200px;
    display:inline-block;
list-style: none;
    text-align:center;
}
```

See example here : http://jsfiddle.net/B7sdp/1/

Comment: I will do! Also, do you know how I would go about centering the images?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `text-align: center;` to `.whatwedo li`

```
.whatwedo li {
width: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
float: left;
    text-align: center;
list-style: none;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/B7sdp/2/)**